# Sync time with Internet?

Tags: c, arduino-esp8266

When my Arduino is starting up, I am trying to sync its time up with the internet and used the following code to do so.  This code has worked in the past but today its never getting out of the while loop so I put some debug statements in the loop to see what's going on.  Looking at the output, it would be in this loop for a long time.  I was given this code so I really don't know what the purpose of the while loop is for.  Any thought or is there a better way sync the time? Thank you for your help!

```
void initTime()
{
 const int MIN_EPOCH = 40 * 365 * 24 * 3600;
 time_t epochTime;

 configTime(0, 0, "pool.ntp.org", "time.nist.gov");

 Serial.print("Fetching time from NTP");

 epochTime = time(NULL);

 while (epochTime < MIN_EPOCH)
 {
   Serial.print(".");
   delay(2000);
   epochTime = time(NULL);

   Serial.print("MIN EPOCH: ");
   Serial.println(MIN_EPOCH);
   Serial.print("EPOCH TIME: ");
   Serial.println(epochTime);
 }

 Serial.println();
 Serial.print("Fetched NTP epoch time is: ");
 Serial.println(epochTime);
}
```

### Output:

Fetching time from NTP.MIN EPOCH: 1261440000

EPOCH TIME: 28810

.MIN EPOCH: 1261440000

EPOCH TIME: 28812

.MIN EPOCH: 1261440000

EPOCH TIME: 28814

.MIN EPOCH: 1261440000

EPOCH TIME: 28816

.MIN EPOCH: 1261440000

EPOCH TIME: 28818

.MIN EPOCH: 1261440000

Comment: @Fredrik Isn't that what `configTime(0, 0, "pool.ntp.org", "time.nist.gov");` does?

Comment: `configTime` seems like it starts up the `sntp` app. If it can't connect, i guess it'll just stay in that loop basically forever (until we hit MIN_EPOCH).

Other than make sure you can connect to the internet, I don't think there's much you can do.

Comment: Again, I was given this code and not sure what's purpose of the loop. I was hoping someone would be able to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

To explain what the loop is doing:

`configTime` starts up (or can start up) an asynchronous process to synch the time every so often. The loop checks and makes sure we have a sane time (40 years after jan 1st 1970 ie Jan 1st 2010). If it's not sane, we wait until we get synched.

I think you might be able to make the SNTP process syncronous, which would mess you up if you got stuck in there.

Comment: Very minor nitpick: the computation `40 * 365 * 24 * 3600` ignores leap years, so it's actually just 14600 days or 39.97 years later, or December 22, 2009.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by changing the wi-fi connection to a different source that my Arduino was connected to and that alone resolved the issue.  Not sure why that resolved the issue but I glad its working now. Thank you for the help!